# How to collect number of days from a month in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column which will have some days from a month in dd-mm-yyyy format. What I need to get total number of days from each month mentioned in that column. The column might not contain all days from each month.

Example :

Column A :

```
2017-01-01
2017-01-02
2017-01-17
2017-01-27
2017-02-08
```

In above example, from 2017 Jan, I have 4 days and from Feb I have one day. I need this count for a `IF` statement to run in C column. ie, in C1 there will be an IF function which will check the month in A1 and count the total number of days for that specific month from A column. If that count is below a specific digit, I need to perform a formula otherwise a different one. This will repeat for all C cell

If this column contains all date from each month I can use Day function to get total days, but here how Can I collect it

Comment: You should do dates in ISO format on SO.

Comment: I can not change date format. It has dependency with other functions

Comment: It's a spreadsheet so it's just formatting. You're not changing the underlying date value - all formulas still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Array formula - use Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
=SUM((MONTH($A$1:$A$5)=MONTH(A1))*(YEAR($A$1:$A$5)=YEAR(A1)))
```

Comment: How is it not correct?  Note my dates (m/d/y) are not the same format as yours (y-m-d) but that doesn't make any difference here as long as your data are actual dates (and not just strings that look like dates)

Comment: I've tried this formula and I don't get the same result as you. I've hit ctrl+shift+enter.

Comment: I am getting value as 1 where I suppose to get 4 (I have to use dd-mm-yyyy format)

Comment: Its working on another sheet. Seems like I have a problem on current one. But Is there anyway I can achieve this without using array function ?

Comment: Just change SUM to SUMPRODUCT as in xenteros' answer

Comment: @acr - formatting doesn't matter - dates are just a number in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

This will work: `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH($A1:$A5)=D1))`

[image]

And an example of manipulating basing on the result:
`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH($A1:$A5)=D1))<3;"good";"bad")`

[image]

Another one when row number represents a month (JAN in C1, FEB in C2...):
`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH($A1:$A5)=ROW()))<3;"good";"bad")`
[image]

In your case:
`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH($A1:$A5)=ROW()))<10;function1();function2())`

Comment: checking it on my sheet

Comment: I am not much familiar with SUMPRODUCT function and also, I dont want to save the count in cell, instead of that I need to use that count as reference point for IF function. In above day count is 4. so I need to compare that 4 with my predefined value say 10 and perform the function

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is not correct one. I suppose to get bad in C2 (day count is greater than 3), but I am getting good.

Comment: I hope you didnt understand my question. I am looking for entire "A" column to calculate count. C1 to C4 should show 4